# Why do I see Inc.com articles as 1x1 GIFs?

Tags: web-server

Joel Spolsky writes articles on Inc.com and regularly links to them from joelonsoftware.com. Whenever I try to read those articles from work (for example, [this one](http://www.inc.com/magazine/20090501/why-circuit-city-failed-and-why-bh-thrives.html?partner=fogcreek)), I see a blank page and the following in the title bar:

```
why-circuit-city-failed-and-why-bh-thrives.html (GIF image, 1x1 pixels)
```

Interestingly:

1) It doesn't matter which browser I use
2) I *am* able to read the articles from home.

Yes, I have brought this to the attention of the folks at Inc.com and even provided a traceroute, but haven't gotten an answer yet.

Now I'm just curious: **what could cause a page to be "seen" as a 1x1 GIF?**

### Update

- I checked with our network guy, and he says we don't filter any sites.
- I had the same problem one day trying to load, from work, a Rails site I'd been building from home on a paid host site. (Right now it loads fine.)

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux machine from which you can wget the article, to maybe assist in locating the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your company is blocking the site.  I'd suggest you ask your work sysadmins the reasoning behind this, doesn't look much to do with the domain itself.

Comment: I guess that's possible, but in two years at work I've never encountered any other blocked site.

Answer (score 2):

When I see 1x1 GIF, I think 'tracking pixel'.  These are 1x1, normally transparent, images that people embed in web pages in order to get your browser to send a request to someplace, usually a third party analytics site, for behavioral analysis purposes.  Why your request would be *replaced* with one I don't know; possibly a brain-damaged implementation of a tracking pixel mechanism, possibly a confused way of doing a block.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a proxy server on your company that blocks images it regards as innapropriate or as ads?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a proxy blocking `favicon.ico`